# How do I get JObject.FromObject(object) to include type information?

Tags: c#, json.net

Suppose I have the following (a very simplified version of my actual code; assume that `Wrapper` and `C` have many more members that aren't shown):

```
interface I { }

class C : I
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Wrapper
{
    public I Instance { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper
        {
            Instance = new C { Name = "Test" }
        };

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
        };

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrapper, Formatting.Indented, settings));
    }
}
```

The output will include the type information of Instance since the actual type is different from its declared type, as expected:

```
{
  "Instance": {
    "$type": "ConsoleApplication.C, ConsoleApplication",
    "Name": "Test"
  }
}
```

Suppose instead that I use a custom `JsonConverter` for `Wrapper`:

```
class WrapperConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Wrapper);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Wrapper wrapper = (Wrapper)value;
        JObject root = new JObject();
        JObject instance = JObject.FromObject(wrapper.Instance);
        root.Add("Instance", instance);
        root.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

This no longer outputs the type information of Instance:

```
{
  "Instance": {
    "Name": "Test"
  }
}
```

How do I force the inclusion of the type information of `Instance` when manually constructing a `JObject` in `WrapperConverter.WriteJson`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to emit `"$type"` information for the root object with `TypeNameHandling.Auto`, you need to use one of the overloads of `JsonSerializer.Serialize()` that has an argument for the *expected* root type:

- [`JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter, Object, Type)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Serialize_1.htm)
- [`JsonSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter, Object, Type)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Serialize_3.htm)

However, as you have noticed, there is no overload of [`JObject.FromObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_FromObject.htm) that allows an expected root type to be passed.  Thus you will have construct the `JObject` manually using a [`JTokenWriter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenWriter.htm):

```
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Wrapper wrapper = (Wrapper)value;
        JObject root = new JObject();
        using (var tokenWriter = new JTokenWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(tokenWriter, wrapper.Instance, typeof(object));
            root.Add("Instance", tokenWriter.Token);                
        }
        root.WriteTo(writer);
    }
```

You could also make that more performant by skipping the intermediate `JObject` representation:

```
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Wrapper wrapper = (Wrapper)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("Instance");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, wrapper.Instance, typeof(object));
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
```

Comment: The using part with the JTokenWriter can be simplified using ```JToken.FromObject(wrapper.Instance, serializer);```

Answer (score 2):

If you modify the `WriteJson` to this:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var wrapper = (Wrapper)value;
    var root = new JObject();
    var instance = JObject.FromObject(wrapper.Instance, new JsonSerializer
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
    });

    root.Add("Instance", instance);
    root.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

It will output the `$type` property as well.

Comment: While this works for Instance, it will also output the `$type` property for all members of Instance as well, which is something I don't want.

Comment: I guess adding attribute `[JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)]` to the other properties is not an option.